# is it possible render a partial from mongoid observer?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, mongoid

I need render a partial content inside observer.

I get this error:

```
undefined method `render' for #<OrderObserver:0xb257a30c>
```

This is my observer:

```
class OrderObserver < Mongoid::Observer
 def after_create(order)
   gift = order.gift
   seller = order.seller
   buyer = order.user
   admin = User.find_or_create_by(email: "email@email.com")
   message = Message.new(subject: "Message subject", body: "<%= #{render 'users/messages/templates/new_order', :order => order} %>", sender: admin, receiver: seller,
                          microfunc: microfunc, order: order)
   message.send_message
   message.save
  end
end
```

**Is it possible render a partial inside mongoid observer?. If it is not possible, How can I do it?**

Thank you very much!

Comment: Well You can just do the same with the ERB.new and passing it a binding object check ERB document on it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this is not possible. An observer is occurring at the Object level, observing when a document is saved and then acting upon that document/object. There is no link between when an object is saved and the browser (since an object can be saved in the console, or a rake task, or anytime the rails environment is loaded).

If you need to create a message when an order is saved, and show that on the screen --- the saving of the message will occur before the order is rendered. So you should be able to render the order (and its messages) as if it happened in one page-load (because it did).

Comment: Thank you very much! But where can I create the message object? on order_controller create action? I had thought that the right way is to do with mongoid observer... Thank you!

Comment: My preference would be to not use an observer, but an observer is fine. You just cannot call render.